# apt-get : unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, aptitude, package-management

I wish to compile `vim7.3` with `python-interp` enabled, which requires `python-dev` package.

The problem is I have `python-2.6.6-2ubuntu2` while `python-dev` requires python-2.6.6-2ubuntu1. (I don't how I got it. http://pastie.org/1706980)

So, I have decided to downgrade python to `-2ubuntu1`. But `apt-get` puts another error message -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 python : Depends: python-minimal (= 2.6.6-2ubuntu1) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed  
E: Broken packages
```

So, how do I resolve this? **Downgrade `python-minimal` first?**
Many packages will be removed then.

Also, `sudo aptitude install python=2.6.6-2ubuntu1` [outputs this.](http://pastie.org/1712658) Telling me to remove quite a few things.
I am not sure this is the right way.

p.s. Google didn't help much.

---

[solved]

Installing `python-dev` from `maverick-updates` worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just install the right [python-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick-updates/python/python-dev) (2.6.6-2ubuntu2) from maverick-updates.

Comment: how different is maverick-updates from main?

Comment: This repository delivers recommended updates for Maverics. You can enable it by selecting Updates > Recommended Updates in the Update Manager.